# How to remove gradient from unity tooltip?

Tags: unity, 16.04, gnome, tooltip

[image: glossy tooltip background]

I prefer flat design, is there a way to disable this on ubuntu 16.04 (GNOME 3.20)?

Comment: Can you define gradient more precisely?  The shadows under the glass menu ?

Comment: The effect where the menu becomes more transparent the further down you look

Comment: Top-Middle area is white. Going down and further is something black. (with some opacity)